# Using the ampersand operator in typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, this, ampersand

How do you create a variable of type AccessGroup

```
declare class AccessGroup {
    id: number;
    active: boolean;
    display_name: string;
    description: string;
    access_group_features: [];
    created_at?: Date;
    created_by?: string;
    updated_at?: Date;
    updated_by?: string;
    static fromJSON(json: any): any;
    toJSON(): this & {
        access_group_features: any;
    };
}
```

What i thought is that we can do it as such

```
let x:AccessGroup={
id:1,
active:false,
display_name:'',
description:'',
access_group_features:[]
toJSON(): ?
}
```

but it gives an error as assigning something to toJSON() is mandatory and don't know about that except the fact the & works like a intersection if I'm not wrong

Can someone give an example as to how toJSON() can be defined for a variable

Comment: Please use copy and paste to show us the **exact** error you get and tell us what line of code it's referencing.

Comment: But fundamentally: You've said that the class has a `toJSON` member, and your object literal doesn't. Since it's not optional, that's what TypeScript is complaining about.

Comment: Re `declare`: Do you really have this class defined somewhere else? `declare` doesn't create the class, it just tells TypeScript that it exists somewhere.

Comment: "*except the fact the & works like a union if I'm not wrong*" `&` makes an *intersection*, not a union. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah my object doesn't have toJSON() cause I didn't how to initialize it.

Comment: @VLAZ my bad it's intersection..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just implement it the same way as you would in a class. That means that you return an object that is based on the object running the method, plus an extra property.

That would look like `{ ...this, extraProp: 'whatever' }`

```
declare class AccessGroup {
    id: number;
    active: boolean;
    display_name: string;
    toJSON(): this & {
        access_group_features: any;
    };
}

let x: AccessGroup = {
    id: 123,
    active: true,
    display_name: 'Testing 123',
    toJSON() {
        return {
            ...this,
            toJSON: this.toJSON, // Make typescript happy
            access_group_features: 'Test'
        }
    }
}
```

And as long as you call that method like `x.toJSON()` then `this` will be the `x` object and everything will work correctly.

As you probably noted though, I needed to explicitly pass in the `toJSON` method as that wasn't getting included in `...this`. I believe this is because in a class the methods are not enumerable. Methods are stored on the class prototype because they do not change per instance. this means that typescript does not believe that `toJSON` will be a property of `{ ...this }`

At least I think, this one is a bit tricky.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwIJjCVBxGA9gK4AO8A3gFDw3wCWwAXPAHZEC2ARiDANzW0oYAC50AbiGacCBCCCgt+teMDrIS0AJ4B9FlHaT4yYTDosA5ktrCCAKQDKAeQByACgCUzYQAs18AGQUAso0Qtio2uaEpNoAZvLCRHDIzAqaVjQAvvyZlJRywvAAHsyY4cj4xGQAvEHKDMwAjABMAMwANMHwQqISXjBEIJ3KqupauvqGAOQAKjiiFvAtrVPD1nZObu51ITRwiTAsO7vKAHTnPmprJ+sOLl6+yKc2d87t8AD0H-AAklPsrAIhUaAAYQQBSIxJBAAd28mnglzQfhY4BwyFgmnOpy6NzC6Mi0RIcQS0JS8Fm8ymuNouWUuUyQA)

---

But having any function in the return of a `toJSON()` probably isn't right either. So you probably don't want to include that at all.

If you change the type to something like:

```
toJSON(): Omit<this, 'toJSON'> & {
    access_group_features: any;
};
```

Then you can leave out the method:

```
toJSON() {
    return { ...this, access_group_features: 'Test' }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwIJjCVBxGA9gK4AO8A3gFDw3wCWwAXPAHZEC2ARiDANzW0oYAC50AbiGacCBCCCgt+teMDrIS0AJ4B9FlHaT4yYTDosA5ktrCCAKQDKAeQByACgCUzR+zrCAPMIAFmoANPAA5DYOLuEAfPAAZBQCyjRC2Kja5oSk2gBm8sJEcMjMCppWNAC+-FWUlHLC8AAezJgZyPjEZAC8ycoMzACMAEwAzCEp8EKiEswmRCCTyqrqWrr6huEAKjiiFvCjY+HL1nZObu79qTRwRTAsFPAAdK9BodNYOMhZOST5hWKOGYOz24XgdWUdTqlCQqHgADEZNcaINWBxuDB4H0jlNzCBhABJYAeZhsLg8J53YqPd7IZ4MCGUKpAA)

---

But creating a plain object to implement a class interface with methods isn't ideal. If you can just actually get that class and then do `new AccessGroup()` your life will probably be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

One small change to what @Alex Wayne has answered above.

The original question had another property in AccessGroup called as access_group_features which is an array

```
declare class AccessGroup {
    id: number;
    active: boolean;
    display_name: string;
    description: string;
    access_group_features: [];
    created_at?: Date;
    created_by?: string;
    updated_at?: Date;
    updated_by?: string;
    static fromJSON(json: any): any;
    toJSON(): this & {
        access_group_features: any;
    };
}
```

> So the access_group property in toJSON() member function should also
> be of the type array ( any other type throws an error as **ampersand**
> operator in typescript intersects the properties and hence should be
> of the same type)

```
toJSON(): this & {
            access_group_features: [];    /* this is probably because of strict type checking in typescript */
        };
```

So the variable created would look something like this:

```
let x: AccessGroup = {
    id: 123,
    active: true,
    display_name: 'Testing 123',
    access_group_features:[],
    toJSON() {
        return {
            ...this,
            toJSON: this.toJSON,
            access_group_features: []
        }
    }
}
```